# React useState method in function doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS and I have some problem with react function. I have simple counter that changes current number depending on the button you clicked. It works fine except the check on minimum and maximum value. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function CounterFunction(props) {

  const {min, max} = props;
  const [cnt, setCnt] = useState(min);

  const decrease = () => {
    setCnt(set(cnt - 1));
  }

  const increase = () => {
    setCnt(set(cnt + 1));
  }

  let set = function(newCnt) {
    console.log("TCL: set -> newCnt", newCnt)
    let cnt = Math.min(Math.max(newCnt, min), max);
    setCnt(cnt);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrease}>Minus 1</button>
      <strong>{cnt}</strong>
      <button onClick={increase}>Plus 1</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And here is App component:

```
import React from 'react';
import MinMaxFunction from './carts/minmax';

export default function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MinMaxFunction min={2} max={10} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I try to increase or decrease number it turns into `NaN`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just for better readability. START writing more, for exmaple `counter`, `setCounter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const decrease = () => {
  setCnt(set(cnt - 1));
}

const increase = () => {
  setCnt(set(cnt + 1));
}

let set = function(newCnt) {
  console.log("TCL: set -> newCnt", newCnt)
  let cnt = Math.min(Math.max(newCnt, min), max);
  return cnt;  // return
}
```

You need to just return `cnt` from `set`.

In `set` you are setting `cnt` to desired value but returning nothing hence `undefined`. In `decrease` and `increase` you are setting `cnt` to return value of `set` which is `undefined` hence `NaN`.

---

Alternate way of doing same thing:

```
const decrease = () => {
  set(cnt - 1); // call the set function, no need of setCnt here
}

const increase = () => {
  set(cnt + 1);
}

let set = function(newCnt) {
  console.log("TCL: set -> newCnt", newCnt)
  let cnt = Math.min(Math.max(newCnt, min), max);
  setCnt(cnt);  // set state just here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `set` is returning `undefined`, because you don't have an return statement there. And you are setting `undefined` in your `setCnt`.
You don't need to pass set into `setCnt`, because you are using `setCnt` inside set. So change the code to:

```
const decrease = () => { set(cnt - 1); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `set` function should return value which is the new number. You didn't use `return` so the computer assumes you're returning nothing. So you need to do `return cnt;`